# Android singleton and static objects lifecycle

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working in a libGDX game for Android and I have a problem managing my assets. I have a class with a singleton pattern. I use an static final variable to access this instance and I also use an [AssetManager](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html&ei=9VKYU77KF-Om0QXC5YDgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHWnxYdfPqBxkfFvkCt-Rn9Fq0PUQ&sig2=ifl_x2d95oP3zBXKImh4Jw&bvm=bv.68693194,d.ZGU) to manage my assets. This manager is created in the constructor and disposed on exit.

My problem is that when I close the game and I launch it again the class instance is the same (was not deleted nor recreated) and the [AssetManager](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html&ei=9VKYU77KF-Om0QXC5YDgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHWnxYdfPqBxkfFvkCt-Rn9Fq0PUQ&sig2=ifl_x2d95oP3zBXKImh4Jw&bvm=bv.68693194,d.ZGU) is still there but disposed, so when I try to load my assets all crash.

Why is not the static instance removed? how long does it take to be removed by the garbage collector? can I remove it manually? is there any way to solve this? I can use [AssetManager#clear](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#clear%28%29) instead [AssetManager#dispose](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#dispose%28%29), but my class store references to all the assets and objects used by the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think ,You might not close the game,It may be gone to background or else ,once come to the foreground or backpressed whatever happen's,it might be called `onResume()` or `onStart()`.while `onResume()` it's not called the corresponding Activity context,So you need to call the `getinstance()` in every `onResume()` or `onStart()` method itself.

create your instance like this

```
public static Singleton getInstance(Activity context){

        mContext = context;
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if(mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```